# Python Calculator: Key Error

Tags: python, dictionary, mapping

I am getting the following error from my code (below):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "2.py", line 29, in <module>
print calculate(raw_input("enter expression"))
   File "2.py", line 27, in calculate
return operations[operation](int(firstnum), int(secondnum))
KeyError: None
```

I have tried going through the code several times, but still do not understand why the correct operation is being assigned to the variable 'operator' and then calling the correct function the dictionary 'operations'.

```
operations = {
    "+": lambda x, y: x + y,
    "-": lambda x, y: x - y,
    "*": lambda x, y: x * y,
    "/": lambda x, y: x / y
}

def calculate(expr):
    firstnum = ""
    secondnum = ""
    operation = None
    print expr
    for char in expr:
        if char.isdigit():
            if firstnum != "":
                secondnum += char
            else:
                firstnum += char
        elif char.isspace():
            break
        elif char in operations:
            operation = char
            print operation
        else:
            raise Exception("invalid character: " + char)
        return operations[operation](int(firstnum), int(secondnum))

print calculate(raw_input("enter expression"))
```

**EDIT: After removing the goofed up indentation, the code processes for example 7*4 but gives the same keyerror at 7 * 4. Don't understand why this is happenning.**

**EDIT2: I simply changed the break to pass**

Thank you everyone!

Comment: remove indent in line `return operations[operation](int(firstnum), int(secondnum))`

Comment: Great calculator program! @luoluo is right. You are returning from the first iteration of your for-loop. In fact, you might want to move the for loop to a separate `parse` function, since it is responsible for parsing, not calculating.

Comment: Did you notice the second condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've goofed your indentation; your `return` is inside your `for`, so it will execute as soon as you get to the end of the first loop. Dedent it once so that it's outside.

Answer (score 0):

The indentation of your `return` statement is incorrect as it's doing it *in* the loop rather than *after* the loop. You need to un-indent that statement by one level.

In addition, your allocation of the digits to the number is off. Only the *first* digit will ever make it into the first number since, after that, it will no longer be `""`. That can be fixed by changing it to use the presence of the operation to decide which number you're creating:

```
if operation is None:
    firstnum += char
else:
    secondnum += char
```

You won't notice this unless you try to use more than one digit in your first number but something like `123+123` will not give you what you expect.

In terms of being able to use spaces within your expression, `break` is not the answer since it will exit the loop early. Perhaps the simplest way to handle this would be to ignore them with `pass`, keeping in mind that will ignore spaces everywhere, including inside numbers.

Comment: I am sort of confused by your extension, as I have ran the code and it works perfectly fine by simply taking the return statement out of the loop. So 7*4 works, but I dont understand why 7 * 4 gives the same error.

Comment: @Syed, try `11*2` and see what you get. Without the extra fix, it will be `12` rather than the correct `22`. That's because only the initial `1` goes to the first number, the second `1` and the `2` go to form the *second* number.  I've updated the answer to make this clearer.